# How to force a window into view

Tags: windows-xp

I work with four monitors and software that displays a great many windows. Every now and then things go wrong and I'll end up with a window that is partially or completely "off the screen". Is there a trick or utility that will help me rescue the windows and bring them back in to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right-click the window in the task bar, and click maximize or restore.

if that doesn't work, right-click some empty space in the task bar and click cascade windows

IF you can get focus on the window, you might be able to try:
alt, left-arrow, down-arrow until you're on "move" option in the context menu, click "move" (space or enter) and then move the window with the arrows keys, press enter when finished.